# EventSource tracing with correlated activity id

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5, etw

I've started using ETW and the out-of-process Semantic Logging Block from Entlib 6.  When I use async/await, the CurrentThreadActivityId is not set on the continuation thread and the TPL framework does not log a transfer event.  This makes it extremely difficult to perform end-to-end tracing.

According to Microsoft's documentation, the TPL framework is supposed to log a transfer event and generate a new activityid, but I can't seem to get it to work.

[Documentation from Entlib 6](https://slab.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ActivityTracingAndSampling)

Here's a small example showing the problem:

To log TPL events, I'm using the following:

```
<eventSource name="System.Threading.Tasks.TplEventSource" level="Informational" matchAnyKeyword="1"/>
```

And here my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncContextTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static Guid _activityId = Guid.NewGuid();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventSource.SetCurrentThreadActivityId(_activityId);
            Console.WriteLine(EventSource.CurrentThreadActivityId);
            Task t = Task.Run(async () => await DoStuffAsync());
            Console.WriteLine(EventSource.CurrentThreadActivityId);

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static async Task DoStuffAsync()
        {
            var x = "one,two,three".Split(',');
            Console.WriteLine(EventSource.CurrentThreadActivityId);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(EventSource.CurrentThreadActivityId);
            var y = String.Join(",", x);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");

        }
    }
}
```

Results

```
334540cc-ccb1-4196-8587-815abf237e4c
334540cc-ccb1-4196-8587-815abf237e4c
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Done
```

Does anyone have a simple example showing the proper way to do end to end tracing with ETW and async/await?

EDIT:

I was able to get this working properly with an in-process listener, but not with the out-of-process listener.  Nothing is logged from TPL.

Comment: This happens because a Console Application uses the `ThreadPoolSynchronizationContext`, which executes continuations on an arbitary threadpool thread. Will you be using ETW from there or is that simply for testing purposes?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - it will be a Windows Service, so yes. I've implemented an STA sync context but there's too much overhead. The point is that await is supposed to log a transfer event and set a new activity id on the new thread. I found out that await is doing its job, but the out-of-process Semantic logging block is not picking it up so I've submitted this as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Nice one :)

Comment: How did you get that working? For me EventSource.CurrentThreadActivityId is always zeroes after await for the sample above?

Comment: If you're using .net 4.6+ you can implement your own wrapper using AsyncLocal. But there is still no great solution to this AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the configuration to use the event source's GUID instead of the name.

```
<eventSource id="2e5dba47-a3d2-4d16-8ee0-6671ffdcd7b5" level="Informational" />
```

Output will look like:

```
605e615a-c849-4ee7-95b8-e6677f945c3f
605e615a-c849-4ee7-95b8-e6677f945c3f
00000001-0001-0000-0c22-0000ffdcd7b5
00000002-0001-0000-0c22-0000ffdcd7b5
Done
```

> Does anyone have a simple example showing the proper way to do end to
>   end tracing with ETW and async/await?

Still looking...